# Why Grails Service Class Is Singleton?

Tags: grails

I came to know that Grails service class are of Singleton type. For what reason, the service classes are defined to be Singleton?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Grails services may be [used with different scopes](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#scopedServices), not *just* `singleton`, by adding something like this to the class:

```
static scope = "flow"
```

From the manual:

- `prototype` - A new service is created every time it is injected into another class
- `request` - A new service will be created per request
- `flash` - A new service will be created for the current and next request only
- `flow` - In web flows the service will exist for the scope of the flow
- `conversation` - In web flows the service will exist for the scope of the conversation. ie a root flow and its sub flows
- `session` - A service is created for the scope of a user session
- `singleton` (default) - Only one instance of the service ever exists

The main reason for choosing `singleton` as the default is for better performance, both in reduced memory usage (only one instance is sitting around), and in reduced processing time, because you eliminate the overhead of creating a new object.

Comment: Now I have a doubt. Lets say I have service named `m1`, which supports transaction. Now two users are accessing `m1` simultaneously, provided that `service` are singleton, how does it handle two users simultaneously along with transaction support?

Comment: There's an [entire section in the manual on transactions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html#declarativeTransactions). Transactions are handled during method calls, so scope does not come into it (as long as you don't store state in the service).